# Ubuntu 16.04 nfs-kernel-server won't start

Tags: nfs, ubuntu-16.04

After a system reboot, nfs-kernel-server was inactive. When I try to start I get

```
nfs-server.service: Job nfs-server.service/start failed with result 'dependency'.
```

which is echoed in journalctl -xe. I am using Ubuntu 16.04.2. Tried a reinstall, and received the same message.

The only flag I can see is that a

```
systemctl list-dependencies nfs-kernel-server
```

gives nfs-mountd.service as failed, while

```
systemctl list-dependencies nfs-mountd.service
```

shows nfs-server.service as failed.

Output of systemctl status:

```
nfs-server.service - NFS server and services
Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/nfs-server.service; enabled; 
vendor preset: enabled)
Active: inactive (dead)
```

while when I try to start the service (journalctl -f),

```
Failed to start NFS Mount Daemon
Dependency failed for NFS server and services.
nfs-server.service: Job nfs-server.service/start failed with result 
'dependency'.
```

Comment: What is the output of `systemctl status nfs-server.service`. Also use `journalct -f` in a shell as root and restart the nfs server in a second shell to watch what is happening during the start.

Comment: There seems to be a detailed thread about this here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nfs-utils/+bug/1590799. I have added what worked for me there, `systemctl add-wants multi-user.taget rpcbind.service` but it seems to be a temporary fix.

Answer (score 1):

Is your Ubuntu server a linux container (lxc) ?

If yes, you need to set something like [explained here](https://github.com/lxc/lxd/issues/2703):

```
mount fstype=rpc_pipefs, mount fstype=nfsd,
```

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu 20.04

My file `/etc/exportfs` had an entry to export a not mounted mount point.
Deleting that entry followed by the commands
`exportfs -rav | sort; service nfs-kernel-server restart;`
solved the problem.